# Array List Last index value checking

Tags: java, arraylist, selenium-webdriver

how will check the last index value for an array list

my code

```
ArrayList<String> admin_pri = (ArrayList<String>) agent_userlist
                    .get("ISadmin");
boolean result = Manageusers.isadmin_check;
            String Actual = " ";
            if (result == true) {    
                Actual = "yes";
            } else {    
                Actual = "No";
            }
            System.out.println("to verify Actual values contains in the list"
                    + admin_pri.get(admin_pri.size() - 1).contains(Actual));
```

in that list Actual value available, but Boolean statement (.contains(actual) its produce false

how will check the last index value

Thanks

prabu

Comment: Well what *is* the value of `admin_pri.get(admin_pri.size() - 1)`? Note that you've got `No` (with a capital letter) but `yes` (with a lower-case start) - are you sure those are correct? (I'd also encourage you to follow Java naming conventions, avoid comparing with boolean literals, use the conditional operator where appropriate, and indent your code more readably.)

Comment: `if(result == true)` is redundant. The `if` checks true and falsity; use `if(result)` instead. Read about it [here](http://codingbat.com/doc/java-if-boolean-logic.html)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `String.contains(CharSequence)` and not the `ArrayList` contains.

When you're calling `admin_pri.get(admin_pri.size() - 1)` you get the string that is last in the list, so the `contains` is called on the result.

If you want to make sure this item is in the list you should call:

```
boolean isContained = admin_pri.contains(Actual);
```

If you want to check that it appears in the last element of the list, use:

```
String lastElement = admin_pri.get(admin_pri() - 1);
boolean isContainedLast = lastElement.equals(Actual);
```